# indices to column vectros of a matrix using "crossvalind"

Tags: matrix, neural-network, cross-validation

i got a 3x50 matrix.  i would like to obtain the 50 3x1 column vectors and assign to them indices using the crossvalind command seen above

```
 Indices = crossvalind('Kfold',N, 10);
```

so lets hypotheticaly say that i had a 3x3 matrix named "input" :

```
input=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
```

how can I imply an index generation for the vector columns of my "input" matrix using crossvalind?

```
 A=[1;4;7]
 B=[2;5;9]
 C=[3;6;9]
```

**the reason i wanna do it is so i can after apply cross validation while having as train/test set these column vectors